# HasTappableComponents class in Flame flutter deprecated

Tags: flutter, gesture, flame

The `onTapDown` method in `GamePlayScreen` doesn't seem to be triggered, and I can't figure out why. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```dart
class FlyingCrowGameStart extends FlameGame with TapCallbacks {
  late final RouterComponent router;
  bool gameOver = false;
  bool showingGameOverScreen = false;
  Vector2 gravity = Vector2(0, 30);

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    await super.onLoad();
    add(router = RouterComponent(initialRoute: 'gameStart', routes: {
      'gameStart': Route(GamePlayScreen.new),
      'gameEnd': Route(GameEndScreen.new),
    }));

    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    ]);
  }

  @override
  void onTapDown(TapDownEvent event) {
    super.onTapDown(event);
    gravity.y -= 20;
    print('main');
  }
}

class GamePlayScreen extends Component with HasGameRef<FlyingCrowGameStart>, TapCallbacks {
  FlyingCrow flyingCrow = FlyingCrow();

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    super.onLoad();
    ParallaxComponent flyingCrowBackground = await gameRef.loadParallaxComponent(
      [
        ParallaxImageData('layers/sky.png'),
        // ... (other image data)
      ],
      baseVelocity: Vector2(5, 0),
      velocityMultiplierDelta: Vector2(1.6, 1.0),
    );
    add(flyingCrowBackground);
    add(flyingCrow);
    add(EnemyCraft());
  }

  void containsLocalPoints(Vector2 point) => true;

  @override
  void onTapDown(TapDownEvent event) {
    super.onTapDown(event);
    gameRef.gravity.y -= 20;
    print('play game');
  }
}
```

Comment: I've included the TapCallbacks mixin in both classes. The onLoad method in GamePlayScreen is successfully loading components. I've verified that the onTapDown method in FlyingCrowGameStart is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`Component` returns false on `containsPoint` since it doesn't have any size etc.
What you can use here instead is the `World`:

```dart
class FlyingCrowGameStart extends FlameGame with TapCallbacks {
  late final RouterComponent router;
  bool gameOver = false;
  bool showingGameOverScreen = false;
  Vector2 gravity = Vector2(0, 30);

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    await super.onLoad();
    add(router = RouterComponent(initialRoute: 'gameStart', routes: {
      'gameStart': Route(GamePlayScreen.new),
      'gameEnd': Route(GameEndScreen.new),
    }));

    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    ]);
  }

  @override
  void onTapDown(TapDownEvent event) {
    super.onTapDown(event);
    gravity.y -= 20;
    print('main');
  }
}

class GamePlayScreen extends World with HasGameRef<FlyingCrowGameStart>, TapCallbacks {
  FlyingCrow flyingCrow = FlyingCrow();

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    super.onLoad();
    ParallaxComponent flyingCrowBackground = await gameRef.loadParallaxComponent(
      [
        ParallaxImageData('layers/sky.png'),
        // ... (other image data)
      ],
      baseVelocity: Vector2(5, 0),
      velocityMultiplierDelta: Vector2(1.6, 1.0),
    );
    add(flyingCrowBackground);
    add(flyingCrow);
    add(EnemyCraft());
  }

  @override
  void onMount() {
    // A bit of a hack until the `WorldRoute` is released.
    parent = game.world;
  }

  void containsLocalPoints(Vector2 point) => true;

  @override
  void onTapDown(TapDownEvent event) {
    super.onTapDown(event);
    gameRef.gravity.y -= 20;
    print('play game');
  }
}
```